# CA Agile Central Rally - Dependencies between tasks

Tags: rally

Similar to adding dependencies between User Stories, Is it possible to add dependencies between tasks within a story ?

Comment: Looks like currently this feature is not available in rally https://communities.ca.com/message/242029455-how-do-you-establish-dependency-between-tasks

Comment: An interesting question is why do you need this?  Stories and tasks are very much intra-team level artifacts- why do you feel the need to track dependencies at this level?